# How to make a reg exp substitution that will substitute only certain occurrences of the same char in Tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to take an expression in tcl and convert its `_` to `<` and `>` if they are around a number. Some examples:

- `bla_bla_4_` -> `bla_bla<4>`
- `bla_bla_4`  -> `bla_bla_4`
- `bla_4_` -> `bla<4>`

How do I do it? I couldn't find it in [regsub's manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regsub.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the right pattern.

```
set parts {"bla_bla_4_" "bla_bla_4" "bla_4_"}
foreach part $parts {
   regsub -all {_(\d+)_} $part {<\1>} result
   puts "$part -> $result"
}
```

This returns

```
bla_bla_4_ -> bla_bla<4>
bla_bla_4 -> bla_bla_4
bla_4_ -> bla<4>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should work:

```
regsub -all {_(\d+)_} $Line "<\\1>" Line
```

Comment: @DonalFellows - More than downvote I would appreciate your comment what is wrong with the code. I didn't test/try it, that's why I wrote **should work**. Your opinion will be appreciate.

Comment: Where is `$Digit_` defined? You want either `\d` or `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: The key point is that Tcl doesn't substitute variables in (braced) regular expressions. (Other RE language variants do, but Tcl's doesn't.) Five seconds testing with an interactive session would have verified that; given that it's a one-liner, there's no excuse for not testing minimally. The fixed version works; you now get an upvote.